# Accounts framework - facebook info - iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get facebook info using the accounts framework and social framework.

I am able to get the relevant data if i pass in the right app ID and i have registered the bundle id of the current Xcode project in facebook. But, if i try to get the same information using a different Xcode project (and the same app ID), the facebook permission dialog box shows up and even i grant permission, i am not granted access.

I know that the bundle ID is important but is there any way for me to get the facebook info of a Xcode project whose bundle ID is not registered on facebook.com.

I am trying to create a static library to grab the users facebook info and i ran into the above problem.

I am using the method (from Accounts framework)
requestAccessToAccountsWithType:options:completion:

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The bundle ID must be set on the Facebook app's settings.